# Locking android device from app

Tags: android

Please help me in how to lock the android device from an app.

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

Used above code but its not working.

Comment: read about how to implement Device Admin API... the code snippet is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Lock the screen you need to Enable Admin Permission.You can check whether device admin is active or not like

`deviceManger.isAdminActive(compName);`

if not then you have to enable it first, and then you can lock the device using

```
deviceManger.lockNow();
```

For further information you can refer this:

[Lock Screen programmatically](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html)